# Identifying this USB-A female to something connector

Tags: usb

I have this USB-A female connector which has three pins on the other side (images attached). Need help identifying what type of interface that is.

My best guess for now is that it is either a 3 pin mini DIN connector or a 3 pin mini XLR connector, but I do not know for sure. If possible, a link to where I can find them would also be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a USB socket for a "universal" notebook power adapter.  Two of the pins will be ground/+5 and the third pin is probably connected to a resistor and one of the other pins to automatically program the power supply to 5V output.

It is almost certainly a custom connector, if you really need to use it, solder wires to the pins and put something standard on the other end of the cable.

This cable is not useful for USB data connections.